# How to disable click with jQuery/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a link that I would like to present with a confirmation. I am using the javascript `confirm()` method. But the only way for me to get the link to not work when the user clicks 'cancel' is to use `return false;`. Is that the correct way to do it (cross-browser)?

```
$('a.confirm').click(function() {
    if(confirm('Are you sure? This cannot be undone.')) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Returning `false` on an event handler, is equivalent to call both `event.preventDefault` and `event.stopPropagation`, your code should work, but what about:

```
$('a.confirm').click(function() {
  return confirm('Are you sure? This cannot be undone.');
});
```

It will return `false` if the user cancels the confirm...

Run that snippet [here](http://jsbin.com/uciyu3).

Comment: I knew there was a better way to do it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See **preventDefault**: http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.preventDefault.28.29

```
$("a").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
});
```